# Regular expression to find two URLS in string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that looks similar to this:

```
|image: http://product_image.png |product: http://product_url.html
```

So, the pattern is |image: URL |product: URL

How can I find these two URLs in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
regex = /image: (.+) \|product: (.+)/
result = regex.match("|image: http://product_image.png |product: http://product_url.html")
puts result[1] # http://product_image.png
puts result[2] # http://product_url.html
```